# What is the most sane way to switch between 5v and 3.3v on a PCB on the same lines?

Tags: pcb, esp8266, 5v, 3.3v

I apologize for the blasphemy I may spit during this question, I am a newbie in electronics.

That said, I want to design a PCB that will house an ESP8266, the chip I selected provides both 5v and 3.3v . On the PCB I want some pin headers for various electronic devices (mostly sensor) that run either on 3.3v or 5v and (some exotic ones) on 12V.

I don't want to bind the PCB on a set configuration and would like each series of pin headers to be switchable (from the ESP8266) between 5v and 3.3v on. So if I have 4 series of pin headers composed by VCC-SIG-GND I would like to be able to switch EACH ONE of them SINGULARLY between 3.3v and 5v. I was thinking of **relays** but then I thought, is there a better way? Is a **transistor**-based circuit a viable solution? **I don't want to use step-ups/down**. I also would like to avoid to run more lines in the PCB.

Staying on topic, I also wanted to reduce the number of pins (from the ESP8266) needed to switch these voltages so I had thought of a shift register like the **74hc595**, that would give me \$ log_{2}n \$ pins needed, but is there a better way (less pins) to do this?

Comment: So you want the same power line to produce 2 different voltages, depending on how you set them with the pin headers? Is that correct? Just want to clarify *exactly* what you are trying to accomplish first.

Comment: Why not use a 4-pin header with +5 - +3.3 - Sig - GND and wire the sensors appropriately. This would eliminate most of the wiring - configuration errors likely with your proposed system.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this switching is better than having fixed supplies. If you're relying on the processor to control the switching it won't be able to do it until it starts up, by which time you may have already destroyed a device by giving it the wrong voltage.

Comment: Is that 3.3v on the data or on the power line? Have you considered using jumpers for this?

Comment: -MCG I want one pin to be able supplied with 3.3 or 5 depending on the setting. The board supplies both 3.3 and 5 (separate pins), I just want to be able to switch between them. -Transistor I'd like to produce the smallest PCB I can with the least circuits. -Finbarr you're right, all the VCC pins (both 3.3 and 5v shared ones) could be controlled by a relay that is controlled by the 8266. Already stumbled across the ESP8266 "flipping" that happens on boot.
-pjc50 Power. The device should be completely operable from remote.Thank you all for your time.

Comment: @Transistor's idea would give you a smaller PCB, because you can leave out all the complicated switching logic and protection circuitry.